# Proving irreducibility of polynomials over the rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Can you provide me with some (easy to use)  lemmas and criteria (besides Eisenstein's)  to prove that a given polynomial is irreducible (if it is) over the rational numbers?

Comment: One thing is Gauss's lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial) which provided it applies you can then do reductions modulo $p$ and see if the reduction is irreducible which may be easier.

Answer (score 3):

[Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion): if the coefficients "spell out" a prime number in any base, then the polynomial is irreducible. More formally, let ${\displaystyle p(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}x+a_{0}}$ with ${\displaystyle 0\leq a_{k}\leq b-1}$ for some ${\displaystyle b\geq 2}$. If ${\displaystyle p(b)}$ is a prime number then ${\displaystyle p(x)}$ is irreducible in ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} [X]}$. Example: $\,x^3+6x^2+9x+3\,$ is irreducible because $\,1693_{10}\,$ is a prime.